# Second order linear nonhomogenous ODE - undetermined coefficients ($y_p = Ae^x$ or $e^x$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a bit confused.

Suppose we have a second order linear non-homogenous ODE of the form

$$y''+6y'+9y = 5e^x$$

We would assume that $y_p$ is of the form $Ae^x$, right?

Now, I have another ODE

$$y'' - 2y' + 2y = 4e^x\sin{x}$$

Where $y_p$ is of the form $y_p = xe^x(A_1\cos{x} + A_2\sin{x})$

My question is: Since we have a number multiplying the $e^x$ in both equations, why didn't we put a coefficient next to $e^x$ in the $y_p$ of the 2nd equation, but in the first one we did?

Comment: Even if we add one for e^x, it can be absorbed by A1 and A2.

Comment: You can do that, and it won't make a difference.

Comment: @Trebor but why? Because there's already a constant which absorbs it?